# Compare all elements of list between themselves

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-itertools

How do I count the occurrences of tuples in a list, regardless of the order of the tuple's items? For example;

```
the_list = [
    (one, two, three),
    (two, three, four),
    (one, three, two),
    (one, two, three),
    (four, two, one),
]
```

In the list above I want `(one, two, three)` and `(one, three, two)` to be equal and be counted as the *same* thing.

Comment: you want to use `permutations`, not `combinations`

Comment: You might want to use sets or frozen sets instead of tuples. Two sets are equal iff they contain exactly the same values (regardless of their order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a counter and sort them before you start counting

```
thelist = [(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,3,2), (1,2,3), (4,2,1)]
from collections import Counter
Counter(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in thelist)
```

```
Counter({(1, 2, 3): 3, (2, 3, 4): 1, (1, 2, 4): 1})
```